# Why is serilog not logging what is in my Blazor wasm .net 6 hosted api controller?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I have a Blazor wasm .net 6 hosted project.

I have configured serilog to log to file and mssqlserver. I works fine for the log from serilog.aspnetcore but when I try Log.Debug(...) in my api controller nothing is logged to the file or sql server.

Program.cs in Blazor.Server

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
           .Build();

        Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel logEventLevelFile = (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel), configuration.GetSection("Serilog:MinimumLevelFile").Value);
        Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel logEventLevelDB = (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel), configuration.GetSection("Serilog:MinimumLevelDB").Value);

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelFile)
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ConnectionStrings:LogDatabase").Value,
                                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelDB,
                                       sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                                       {
                                           TableName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:TableName").Value,
                                           SchemaName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:SchemaName").Value
                                       },
                                       appConfiguration: configuration
                                       , columnOptionsSection: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ColumnOptions"))
               .CreateBootstrapLogger();

        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
        {
            Debug.Print(msg);
            Debugger.Break();
        });

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Application starting up.");

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "The application failed to start up correctly.");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).UseSerilog();

        return builder;
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevelFile": "Debug",
    "MinimumLevelDB": "Debug",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "LogDatabase": "...valid connection string ..."
    },
    "SchemaName": "dbo",
    "TableName": "Logs"
  },
```

UserController.cs

```
public UserController(){}

    // GET: api/user
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string empId)
    {
        Log.Debug($"{HttpContext.Request.Path} => Loading current user from Query String: {empId}");
        ....
```

I have a very similar project in .net 6 (Angular instead of Blazor wasm) and everything works fine
The user controller is the same.

I have tried to move the configuration around, like moving it in the .UseSerilog() of CreateHostBuilder but not luck.

Why is serilog not logging what is in my api controller?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default logging level of 'Information' was applied even if I was setting the level for each sinks.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelFile)
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ConnectionStrings:LogDatabase").Value,
                                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelDB,
                                       sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                                       {
                                           TableName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:TableName").Value,
                                           SchemaName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:SchemaName").Value
                                       },
                                       appConfiguration: configuration
                                       , columnOptionsSection: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ColumnOptions"))
               .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```

Forcing the minimum level to Verbose fixed the issue

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.File("logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month, restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelFile)
                .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ConnectionStrings:LogDatabase").Value,
                                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: logEventLevelDB,
                                       sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                                       {
                                           TableName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:TableName").Value,
                                           SchemaName = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:SchemaName").Value
                                       },
                                       appConfiguration: configuration
                                       , columnOptionsSection: configuration.GetSection("Serilog:ColumnOptions"))
               .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```